# I cant install app manually on my ledger nano s

Tags: python, cryptography, hardware, cryptocurrency

So there is project idena.io, and community made ledger nano s app https://github.com/idelse/idena-ledger
and when I run it normally I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/toni/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ledgerblue/loadApp.py", line 197, in <module>
    dongle = getDongle(args.apdu)
  File "/home/toni/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ledgerblue/comm.py", line 216, in getDongle
    dev.open_path(hidDevicePath)
  File "hid.pyx", line 74, in hid.device.open_path
OSError: open failed
```

With sudo i get this

```
ERR: ledgerblue pip package not found.
please install using 'pip3 install ledgerblue'
```

I installed it 100 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here just need to run one command I hope i it fixed it for someone

https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005165269-What-if-Ledger-Wallet-is-not-recognized-on-Linux-